# HBase: How to a column(s) to a column, not to a family column

Tags: hbase

If possible, can someone give me an example of how to add a column, or columns, to an existing column belonging to an existing column family? I know how to add a column to a column family.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "Adding column to an existing column but not to a column family"?

Comment: A column family consist of 1 or more columns as determined by the key of a key:value pair inserted into that column family. But can the value itself represent a set of key:value pairs?

Comment: You can store your key:value in json format in on column

Comment: Nishu, I think your comment is in agreement with Matteo's response.

Comment: Yes, he is also referring the same approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put whatever you want in a HBase column: a JSON, a serialized Avro, etc. Simply put under your existing column a more complex structure. But you cannot put another column qualifier under an existing one. You have to respect the `table -> column family -> column -> anything` structure.